# Has Bennett (former Israeli prime minister) said what his stance on Palestine is?

Tags: israel, palestine, naftali-bennett

There was a new PM of Israel sworn in recently, and one of the most internationally important issues regarding Israel is them & Palestine. Has Bennett  said his stance on Palestine?

Comment: Bennett wrote about this in the [NY times](https://www.nytimes.com/2014/11/06/opinion/naftali-bennett-for-israel-two-state-is-no-solution.html)

Comment: @Mordechai that’s hidden behind paywall sadly :( If you can access it you could post it as an answer along with a summary and/or relevent quoted.

Comment: There is a relevant video on his official YouTube channel: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n1oFOEY_6lM

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Quoting the sub-heading from a [Jerusalem Post](https://www.jpost.com/israel-news/sports/can-bennett-stand-up-to-us-on-settlements-palestinian-state-670925) article:

> Bennett throughout his political career has been clear that he believes that all of Area C, where all the Israeli settlements are located should be part of sovereign Israel.

This is even "stronger" than Bennett being against granting the Palestinians a state in the future as it is taking away some of what they do have right now, some semblance of autonomy in the West Bank.  So, what Jacob3 said - he is against a 2 state solution - but even more so and, in essence, partial annexation.

Now, for a bit of Israel-specific context:  **you have to separate Bennett's views, *as the leader of a political party*, from what the actions and intentions of the newly-elected *government* might be.**

To keep in power, an Israeli government usually has to navigate between competing priorities and wishes of Knesset members, something Netanyahu was a master at.  It does not always align exactly with the positions of its Prime Minister.

Most notably, the coalition to oust Netanyahu included [a party representing Israeli Arabs](https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2021/6/14/israel-bennetts-win-and-netanyahus-dangerous-defeat) (who normally sit out coalitions, I believe).  With 4 members, they could easily derail the new government.

This is more a coalition to boot Netanyahu than anything else and inferring how it will engage with the Palestinians is probably above most people's pay grade, especially during the early days, when Netanyahu will be their biggest problem.

In fact, the coalition apparently decided to momentarily [put aside the Palestinian question](https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/news/international/world-news/explainer-whos-who-in-israels-new-patchwork-coalition-government/articleshow/83509377.cms), doing so was explicitly part of how it was put together:

> It is expected to focus mostly on economic and social issues rather than risk exposing internal rifts by trying to address major diplomatic matters such as the Israeli-Palestinian conflict.

Comment: United Arab List (Ra'am) has 4 members.

Comment: "he is against a 2 state solution - but even more so and, in essence, partial annexation." is he against partial annexation? against partial annexation instead in favour for a complete annexation?

Comment: "To keep in power, an Israeli government usually has to navigate between competing priorities and wishes of Knesset members, something Netanyahu was a master" can you cite some examples?

Comment: This is interesting cause I heard that Angela Merkel too was a master but in her own terms (some german name for some german political practice perfected by Kohl and his prodigy Merkel)

Answer (score 19):

I found this quote on [his Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naftali_Bennett) "I will do everything in my power to make sure they never get a state".

Comment: This is a great answer. Short and to the point.

Comment: @ISupportTheBoycott And completely lacking nuance. "According to Israeli journalist Anshel Pfeffer, those who have worked with Bennett have privately said that much of his rhetoric is for electioneering purposes, and he is in fact more moderate than believed." from the same Wikipedia page.

Comment: @ZevSpitz, After he's joined the left, contradicting what he has said dozens of times, I doubt he can be believed with anything. But this is nevertheless the simple answer to the question. - I Support Israel! (if it's not customary to express political views on this site, than I'll have to put it in my User Name).

Comment: @ZevSpitz That isn't relevant nuance for this question however. The question is, "Has Bennet **said** what his stance on Palestine is?". This answer contains something that Bennett said. Your quote contains something that a journalist said that a colleague said about their opinion of Bennett. It's not relevant and (a) it's so far removed from the source that it's impossible to know how accurate it is, and (b) it's so broad that it is impossible to know whether it applies to Bennett's views on Palestine specifically.

Comment: @ZevSpitz searching in Hebrew brings endless results about Bennet opposing a Palestinian state since at least 2014, so are his political party and voters. I don't think it is election rhetoric, and this seems like the best answer to this question. If someone would ask if Bennet is going to actively oppose a Palestinian state then you can have other arguments, for example political pragmatism and that all the big peace agreement in Israel were signed by extreme right leader e.g. [Menachem Begin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menachem_Begin) returning Sinai to Egypt